# Unique parallelograms formed by two sets of intersecting parallel lines

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider 11 parallel lines intersected by another 15 parallel lines. How many different parallelograms with vertices placed at the points of intersections and sides on the lines are there.

**My Solution:**

To form a parallelogram we just choose any 2 of the 11 and any 2 of the 15 to form the parallelogram. So $$C(11,2) * C(15,2)$$

But this overcounts the parallelogram as it counts the points on the diagonal and at least double counts each parallelogram. Any way to encounter this?

**similar question** - [Parallelograms formed by parallel lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772062/parallelograms-formed-by-parallel-lines)

Comment: The way I understand, $\binom{11}{2}*\binom{15}{2}$ is correct

Comment: There is no double counting with that argument. A parallelogram is made from two pairs of parallel lines. From the set of 11 lines, you must pick two, then from the set of 15 you must pick two, independently of the first pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would solve it is to assign coordinates to these intersection points $(i,j)$. This will be the starting point of a diagonal. Choose the other point of the diagonal $(i', j')$ in such a way that $i'>i$ and $j'>j$. That way you count parallelograms only once. For a given $i$ and $j$, you have $(11-i)(15-j)$ possible $(i',j')$ vertices. So the number of parallelograms is $$\sum_{i=1}^{11-1}\sum_{j=1}^{15-1}(11-i)(15-j)$$